# How to get the output stream from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I currently have several runnable classes, each printing a string upon completion using `System.out.println()`.

In the `main()` I execute them using a ExecutorService ,`executor.execute()` for each of them.

I am wondering after executing those threads, `how to get the output stream from them for future use ?`

Pretty much like using `.getInputStream` for processes but there's no such method in the Thread class. Thanks!

There's a class which implements runnable interface like this:

```
public class A implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
       System.out.println(5);         //this thread always print out number 5
   }
}
```

and in the main function I need to get the printed number and store it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService ThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    ThreadPool.execute(new A());     //This statement will cause the thread object A 
                                     //to print out number 5 on the screen
    ThreadPool.shutdown();
    ......
}
```

Now I need to get the printed number 5 and store it into, say an integer variable.

Comment: Doesn't thread write to the same output stream as the process it's parent process, this would be natural since they share memory, they would naturally share underlying file descriptors.

Comment: I don't quite understand? Each thread outputs using System.out.println()

Comment: Isn't output stream a shared resource i.e. you need to access it in one thread at a time - I might be wrong.

Comment: @hagubear It is shared, but you don't need to enforce exclusive access, unless your messages are printed with multiple commands.

Comment: @Austin What luk32 is asking is: Why would you need to "get" it from the thread? System.out is shared as is, whatever thread or executor you use it from.

Comment: correct me if im worng, are you expecting return type from thread?

Comment: Thx for all the replies! What I'm trying to get is the string from the System.out.println() statement in all the threads. I need to get them for other usage not simply displaying them on the screen.

Comment: @LMK Not exactly cuz the threads only print out the result instead of return a String

Comment: So create String object in your thread, print it with System.out.println(), and return String from this thread. You can use Callable<String>. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Comment: @pomkine Unfortunately.,..I'm not allowed to return anything from the thread..

Answer (score 2):

I think below code will satisfy your requirement.

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<InputStream>
{
    @Override
    public InputStream call() throws Exception {
        //InputStream inputStreamObject = create object for InputStream
        return inputStreamObject;
    }
} 
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<InputStream>> list = new ArrayList<Future<InputStream>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            Callable<InputStream> worker = new MyCallable();
            Future<InputStream> submit = executor.submit(worker);
            list.add(submit);
        }
        InputStream inputStreamObject = null;
        for (Future<InputStream> future : list) {
            try {
                inputStreamObject = future.get();
                //use inputStreamObject as your needs
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. But I'm wondering how can I construct the inputstream object from a thread in the call() method?

Comment: What you are going to achieve by getting inputstream object? In the question you didn't mentioned it properly. Please update your full requirement.. Still your question is vague.. As per your question just I return the object of inputstream.

Comment: I have updated the description. I would greatly appreciate it if you can take a look :)

Comment: Instead Callable<InputStream> use Callable<String> now future.get() will return String object. You can process with string. Whether my answer is right for your question?

Comment: Sorry but can I ask for more details for the callable class?

Comment: First you learn the difference between runnable and callable. Just see my below answer which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Runnable and Callable in thread:**

`runnable` interface has a method `public abstract void run();` void - which means after completing run method, it will not return anything. `Callable<V>` interface has a method  `V call() throws Exception;` which means after completing call method, it will return Object `V` that is parametrized as

```
public class Run_Vs_Call {
    public static void main(String...args){
        CallableTask call = new CallableTask();
        RunnableTask run = new RunnableTask();
        try{
            FutureTask<String> callTask = new FutureTask<String>(call);
            Thread runTask = new Thread(run);
            callTask.run();
            runTask.start();
            System.out.println(callTask.get());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static class CallableTask implements Callable<String>{
        public String call( ){
            String stringObject = "Inside call method..!! I am returning this string";
            System.out.println(stringObject);
            return stringObject;
        }
    }   
    public static class RunnableTask implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            String stringObject = "Inside Run Method, I can not return any thing";
            System.out.println(stringObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use new static class:

```
public class Global{

//example
 public static ..
 public static ..
}
```